# How to insert multiple data in firebase using loop

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Is there any way to insert multiple data in firebase using loop in android studio.
As

```
for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren())
{
        String Name = ds.child("Name").getValue().toString();
        list.add(Name);
}
```

DataSnapshot loop is used to get the multiple children. How can i insert multiple data using loop.

Comment: The code you shared does not insert any data into Firebase. To learn how to write to Firebase, have a look at the [documentation on reading and writing data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write).

Comment: What data would you like to insert? What is your database structure? Please responde with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo, I want to insert the name of users ... database structure is  : Root
                                                 |
                                                 User
                                                         | Name 1
                                                         |
                                                         Name 2
                                                         |
                                                         So on

Comment: @AbbasAli if you found my answer useful, consider marking it as correct, it helps future readers and I'd appreciate that. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you want to update various children of your database at once and for that you do not need to actually use a loop to insert multiple data at once in Firebase.

You may use maps for that, which can update multiple fields of your database in one go. The code for using maps, looks something like this:

```java
Map<String,Object> taskMap = new HashMap<>();
taskMap.put("age", "12");
taskMap.put("gender", "male");
taskMap.put("name", "Someone");
taskMap.put("surname", "no-one");
reference.updateChildren(taskMap);
```

This depends a lot on your database structure, and you can edit it for your need, according to your database structure.

To know more about, how to update database using maps, go through the following links:

[Link1](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#update_specific_fields)
and
[Link2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=19&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwji4prT-7feAhXQy6QKHbWvASYQrAIoADASegQICBAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fstackoverflow.com%2Fquestions%2F47560647%2Ffirebase-save-object-with-map-property&usg=AOvVaw2p3iJ-Wp4YqKqZIRvnqdSr).

Also, if you could make the question a bit more precise, you can get more help from here.